# What does the following statement do - df.groupby("level")["attempt"].mean()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, analytics

Ok, so I was looking through some data analysis (very *basic*) projects. I came across this line-

```
print(df.groupby("level")["attempt"].mean())
```

Where df is the dataframe of the file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whitehatjr/Data-Analysis-by-visualisation/master/data.csv

Basically, as far as I can tell, It is the data of Grade 3 students who attempted a quiz, which had levels. Now, the only usages of groupby() I knew were -

```
#First Usage
q = df.groupby('')

#Second Usage
w = df.groupby(['', ''])
```

Can someone please explain to me, what the statement print(df.groupby("level")["attempt"].mean()) actually is?

Comment: It's the average of the `attempt` column for each value of `level`.

Comment: Your example uses of `groupby()` are not the normal way to use it. Usually you group by one or more actual columns.

Comment: @Barmar Ohk, so like the first value groups it by that column, and then the second one displays only that value of the level? And in this example, the column will be sorted by level and corresponding it would be the mean of the attempts in that level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the top-level description from the pandas [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) docs:

A groupby operation involves some combination of splitting the object, applying a function, and combining the results. This can be used to group large amounts of data and compute operations on these groups.

In this context, you are using the values of the column 'level' to split the dataframe.

You then select only the column "attempt" and apply the mean function, the values of which are then combined back together.

So in english, your results are the mean value for all records of each 'level'. That is, in the example below, the mean attempt value for all records of level 1 is 0.75144

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whitehatjr/Data-Analysis-by-visualisation/master/data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
df.groupby("level")["attempt"].mean().reset_index()
```

output:

```
     level   attempt
0  Level 1  0.751445
1  Level 2  0.863281
2  Level 3  0.698113
3  Level 4  0.734694
```

Comment: And, if we were to remove the .mean(), would we get 2 columns- Level and Attempt, where level would be sorted from 1 - 4  and the corresponding values of attempt??

Comment: you can [iterate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) over a groupby object: `for grp, dfg in df.groupby("level"): ..`

Answer (score 1):

Assume a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6],
                            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]).T,
                  columns=['level', 'attempt'])
```

Now, `df.groupby("level")` is grouping your dataframe based on the values of "level" column: you will have a group for `level==1`, one for `level==2`, etc.

```
In [1]: df.groupby("level").get_group(1)
Out[1]: 
   level  attempt
0      1        1
1      1        2
2      1        3
3      1        4
```

Then you are asking for "attempt" column (here we have only two columns, but you may have more). For `level==1`:

```
In [2]: df.groupby("level")["attempt"].get_group(1)
Out[2]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
```

Finally you are computing the mean of the grouped column. For `level==1`:

```
In [3]: df.groupby("level")['attempt'].mean()[1]
Out[3]: 2.5
```

Final result would be:

```
In [4]: df.groupby("level")["attempt"].mean()
Out[4]:
level
1    2.50
2    5.50
3    6.25
4    2.50
5    4.50
6    7.50
```

Comment: If you delete the `mean`, you'd have a `pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object`. You may access and elaborate its values in many ways. Take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html)